# Change "Last-Modified" response

Tags: php

There emerged a problem I could not cope with. I need to set Last Modified response. 
If I write the following code, everything is fine:

```
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $mt).' GMT');
```

But if I then add echo 'Test'; in the end:

```
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $mt).' GMT');
echo 'Test';
```

it fails. Last Modified header is not displayed in response headers.

What’s the problem with it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

After `Test` you try to finish your string literal with a `U+2019 : RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` character instead of with a `U+0027 : APOSTROPHE`.

This causes PHP to throw an error page.

If you replace `’` with `'` it works normally, and the header is set.

Comment: @Gopher — After your edit, I can't reproduce the problem: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAMO3IvOYZ9ATpo2kLFdYFaBqu8ASvmcNYQ